# How to remove images from dictionary

Tags: dictionary, text-prediction

How can I stop Google dictionary offering me pictures when I type words?

If I type "happy"... I want the word not the image (☺).

It's so annoying. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that it is not your keyboard app? mine has a setting about 'emojis'

Comment: I just have stock keyboard. Android 5.1... How do I change it please?

Comment: I assume you're using Google Keyboard. Check its keyboard setting (Settings - Language & input - Google Keyboard - Text correction - Add-on dictionaries - Emoji for English words)